# can't define a new variable to hold my rlist

Tags: ocaml

I'm learning about imperative programming in Ocaml and I have the following situation where I'm trying to reverse a linked list:

these are my two defined types:

```
type cell = { data : int; next : rlist; }
and rlist = cell option ref
```

and here is my function reverse:

```
let reverse (head:rlist) = 
  let rec helper ((head: rlist),(tmp: rlist)) = 
    match !head with 
    | None -> tmp 
    | Some c when !(c.next) = None ->
        c.next := !tmp ; tmp := Some c ; tmp
    | Some c ->
        let a = ref Some !(c.next) ;
        c.next := !tmp ;
        tmp := Some c ;
        helper (a,tmp) 
  in
  helper (head, ref None)
```

this version will give me Syntax error but if I replace: `let a = ref Some !(c.next)` with `head := !(c.next)` it will work. Therefore, there is something wrong with the declaration of my let.

Answer (score 2):

This expression:

```
ref Some !(c.next)
```

is parsed like this:

```
(ref Some) !(c.next)
```

essentially because function application in OCaml has very high precedence.

You should parenthesize like this:

```
ref (Some !(c.next))
```

After fixing this problem you have another syntax problem. This expression:

```
let a = ref (Some !(c.next));
```

is not valid. You need to have `in` after `let`. The short description is that inside a function `let` is used to introduce a local variable, and the expression that uses the local variable appears after `in`. The `in` is required. You can fix this by changing the `;` at the end to `in`.

After fixing these two syntax problems you have at least one type error. But I hope this helps you make progress.